# How to add optional arguments to rsDriver after starting the browser

Tags: r, rselenium

How can I add extra arguments to a session while it is running? For example, go headless after starting the server.

In the example below, the server is setup. Navigate to Stackoverflow login page, add in credentials and log in. I would then like to go headless.

My attempt was to manually add in the headless argument to `extraCapabilities` but this does not seem to work.

In this scenario, I would like to go headless after login. How can I do this?

```
my_email <-  ""
my_password <-  ""
login_url <- "https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2f"


rD <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox", 
               verbose = FALSE)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]

remDr$navigate(login_url)

login_element = remDr$findElement("css selector", "#email")
login_element$sendKeysToElement(list(my_email)) 

password_element = remDr$findElement("css selector", "#password")
password_element$sendKeysToElement(list(my_password)) 

login_button = remDr$findElement("css selector", "#submit-button")$clickElement()

remDr$extraCapabilities <- list("moz:firefoxOptions" = list(args = list('--headless')))
```

Comment: What is your purpose?

Comment: I need to interact with my browser for one step, sometimes on some websites I have to randomly fill a ReCAPTCHA. I just need to fill it once. After that I would like to go headless. This is because I would like to refresh a page as fast as possible. i.e. I've set a while loop. as soon as it hits my desired time. let's say 6pm. The while loop finishes, the page refreshes. So I would like to minimise this refresh time. I believe going headless and removing images will decrease the refresh time. (note I only refresh once so I'm not spamming the page).